# How to deactivate embedded feature selection in caret package?

Tags: r, feature-selection

I am writing a machine learning code using caret package in R. A sample  of code could be

```
weighted_fit <- train(outcome,
                          data = train,
                          method = 'glmnet',
                          trControl = ctrl)
```

As you know, some methods in caret package have built-in feature selection such as elastic net. My question is that is there any way to deactivate the built in feature selection in this code?

Thanks in advance for any comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
#I will try to answer this question to the best of my ability:
#The train function in caret package comes with a parameter tuneGrid which can be used to create a data-frame of tuning parameters.

#The tuning parameter of elastic net regularization in glmnet() is alpha, so create the following:
glmgrid <- expand.grid(alpha = 0) will give ridge regularization.
glmgrid <- expand.grid(alpha = 1) will give lasso regularization.

#and then use 

weighted_fit <- train(outcome,
                          data = train,
                          method = 'glmnet',
                          trControl = ctrl,
                          tuneGrid = glmgrid)

#In glmnet in r , the alpha values can be in the range [0,1] i.e. 0 to 1 including 0 and 1.


# GLMNET - https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/glmnet/versions/2.0-18/topics/glmnet
# CARET - https://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html
```